# Twitter Data Set Filtering

Tags: csv, twitter, analysis

I have a big twitter data set with about 3 million @mention records in a csv file. I also have the usernames of people who are being mentioned in the data set. I want to create a separate data set from this with 3 columns 1)username of person being @mentioned 2)who is @mentioning 3) how many times the person has been @mentioned by the user. I know that going through the huge data set one by one will be pretty time consuming. Is there any other short way or software to sift through the data and produce the results as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Asking for software recommendations is off-topic for StackOverflow. My recommendation is to use Python!

To the core of the question:

Since your data is a CSV file and not a database with an index, you *do* have to do this line by line.

Do get started, write a program to read this file line by line and produce the desired output format.

Comment: If I have it in a database how do I go about producing the results.